# how to find the index based on rowposition and column position

Tags: javascript

I have an two-dimenstional array..

I know the rowposition and column position.

How to find the index of the array based on the row position and column position.

```
Ex: if rowPosition =1 and columnPosition = 1,
```

the index should be 2.
The Pictorial representation is

```
      0      1
      2      3
```

Comment: I don't think you mean index. That refers to the position in the array. What you are trying to access is the _value_ at an index (or in this case at a rowIndex and a colIndex.

Answer (score 1):

The value you are trying to access can be obtained by doing `array2D[rowPosition][columnPosition]`.

Example:

```
var array2D=[[0,1],[2,3]];
alert(array2D[1][1]);
```

Note that both the row and column indices are 0-based, so [1][1] yields 3.